# C# combobox autocomplete reset value

Tags: c#, autocomplete, combobox

In general my problem is, I made autocomplete on windows.forms.combobox and when I type in first letter drop down list opens and provides me a list of cities as intended to work but when I start typing another letter to restrict autocomplete list, first letter is erased and switched with my new letter which becomes first and only letter in combobox. I used textchanged event to perform autocomplete feature.

Please help,

thanks in advance!

Comment: some code would be welcome.

Comment: Can I do something like: KeyDown event fires first, get the letter I type in and then KeyDown calls textchanged event and hand it the written letter?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manually implement `AutoComplete` for a `ComboBox`. It already has this feature. Just do this:

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

You can also set these properties via properies windows of a `ComboBox` control.

[image]

Comment: I have already implemented this solution with one exception, I set AutoCompleteSource to CustomSource and source for the AutoCompleteCustomSource property is AutoCompleteStringCollection.

Comment: With using cuatom source you have to provide a custom source for auto complete to work, but in your case it so much easier to set the `AutoCompleteSource` to ListItems, it works perfecty.